# Running Concurrent .jar Processes within Python

Tags: java, python, concurrency, jar

I have two .jar files that I want to call from a Python script. However, after I call the first jar, the terminal sits and doesn't process anything after that point as the server is running. The server starts fine, but I want to start another process that will run until I ask them to stop.

I've had trouble searching for possible solutions because I'm unsure of what terminology to use.

```
from subprocess import call 
import glob 
import sys 

h2 = glob.glob("h2*.jar")
reasoner = glob.glob("reasoner*.jar")

h2 = h2.pop()
reasoner = reasoner.pop()

call(["java", "-jar", h2, "-tcp"]) # Any call commands after this point don't execute
```

Comment: `subprocess.call` documentation "Wait for command to complete". Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) which wait the sub-process to terminate.

```
from subprocess import Popen

...

Popen(["java", "-jar", h2, "-tcp"])
```

FYI, [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/) is good place to look, especially [`subprocess` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for this specific problem.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to wait the sub-process explicitly when you're using `Popen`, save the reference to the Popen object and use [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method:

```
proc = Popen(["java", "-jar", h2, "-tcp"])
# Do something else ..
proc.wait()  # block execution until the sub-process terminate.
```

Comment: Thanks! However, now that I have both running, when I kill the application through Ctrl+C the first process that I started never gets killed along with it. Do I have to catch the KeyboardInterruption?

Comment: @AmericanKryptonite, I updated the answer. Is that what you want?